# problems with configuring paypal (europe) with prestashop - 2 questions that I don't understand

Tags: paypal, prestashop

I am having great difficulty in getting paypal to work in my prestashop. I live in Finland.

When i installed prestashop it was an american version (pounds and ounces, american defaults etc) it also had american Paypal which can't be configured in Europe.

After hours of trying I managed to work out how to install PayPal europe module from the prestashop modules page (no istructions with download). I dowmnloaded onto my laptop and ftp'd it into the modules folder.

I am now trying to configure the paypal plugin but am confused because it isn't saving and not saying what the errors are.

I think that the errors are to do with a question about PayPal which are, cliend ID and secret
I have no idea what these refer to and the paypal installation guide doesn't mention them. Can someone tell me what these are and where I can find them?

I've appended (hopefully) a screen printout - well i aint cause I aint allowed! just aint fair!

Comment: For client Id and Secret you need to create an REST application at developer.paypal.com . You can follow the below link for more info :https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/admin/manage-apps/